# How do i reset my UEFI firmware settings with no display and without touching th mainboard?

Tags: motherboard, uefi

I am using Asrock B560 PRO4 mainboard And i need to reset the firmware settings without the display and without touching the mainboard

Comment: What you ask is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the computer and remove bios battery, wait 30 seconds. Put battery back, plug and hit the power button.

This will reset everything ...

If you want to reset settings in your uefi partition then open with a linux usb with ssh server running on it then connect via ssh to the machine mount uefi partition (Apple , or Windows) get inside it restore original uefi boot file (boot64.efi in some cases)

If you dont have any second computer on your network to connect via ssh. You can use your cellphone with terminal applicaiton (termux in linux)

Note that, UEFI shell is part of motherboard firmware. UEFI partition is part of operating system disk.

Good luck